# Scriptural references for Jivas getting Moksha in Shiva loka

Tags: scripture, shiva, moksha, shaivism, lokas

Are there any Scriptural references which state that Jeevas can Attain Moksha on reaching Shiva loka and not fall back in Samsara?

Comment: Isn’t that obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShAstras describe two categories of people who attain Shivaloka. Those who are inclined to Gyana and those inclined towards bhoga (enjoyment).

Those who are inclined towards Gyana attain mukti there itself by obtaining Shivagyana (knowledge of Shiva). Others who are inclined towards bhoga are reborn.

> भोगाः शिवपुरे तस्य ज्ञेयाः सातिशयाः शुभाः १०। स्थानप्राप्तिः परं
> तुल्या भोगाः शांतिमयाः स्थिताः । कुर्यात्पुण्यं
> महत्तस्मान्महाभोगजिगीषया ११। सर्वातिशयमेवैकं भावितं च सुरोत्तमैः ।
> आत्मभोगाधिपत्यं स्याच्छिवः सर्वजगत्पतिः १२।
> **केचित्तत्रैव मुच्यंते ज्ञानयोगरता नराः । आवर्तंते पुनश्चान्ये संसारे भोगतत्पराः १३।** तस्माद्विमुक्तिमिच्छंस्तु भोगासक्तिं च वर्जयेत् ।
> **विरक्तः शांतचित्तात्मा शिवज्ञानमवाप्नुयात् १४।**
>
> *As the earth is said to be a common place for all beings, in the same way the city of Śiva is (said be a common place) for all the devotees
> of Śiva. As here (i.e. on the earth) enjoyments for all beings are
> said to be abundant, in the same way they are said to be many in
> Śiva’s city, due to the preeminence of various (kinds) of religious
> merit. As even the good or bad fruit (of their acts) is enjoyed by all
> human beings, the fruit of the acts (enjoined) by Śiva is religious
> merit. One gets excellent, good enjoyments in Śiva’s city, especially
> according to his faith, in accordance with his religious merit. He
> gets an (excellent) place, his undisturbed enjoyments are comparable
> to final beatitude. 11b-13. Therefore, to win great enjoyments one
> should do great meritorious acts. There would be (i.e. he would have)
> supremacy (i.e. control) over his own enjoyments, which alone is
> honoured by best gods as superior to everything. **Some men engrossed
> in the pursuit of knowledge (Gyanayoga) become free there only. Others intent on
> enjoying pleasures again come back to the mundane existence.**
> Therefore, he who desires salvation should give up attachment to enjoyments. **He, being detached, and with his mind and heart tranquil,
> would obtain the knowledge of Śiva.***

***~ Padma PurAna, Bhumi Khanda, Chapter 69***